# Ordenar datos por fecha de una DB Firestore en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, aplicación-web, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy trabajando una pequeña aplicación CRUD con Firestore, soy nuevo usando dicha plataforma, necesito ordenar los datos que ingresé por fecha (De la más antigua a la más nueva), según la documentación de Firestore esta linea de código ayuda:

```
citas_registradas.orderBy("fecha")
```

Pero dicho código sólo me muestra un dato de los 5 que tengo ingresado, mi DB se llama citas_registradas y mis campos serían: nombre,fecha,hora,teléfono, agradecería su apoyo ya que soy algo inexperto y estoy aprendiendo, gracias.

CÓDIGO DE LA LECTURA DE DATOS js DE FIRESTORE A UNA TABLA HTML:

```
/*LEER DATOS DE FIRESTORE*/
var tabla = document.getElementById('tabla');
db.collection("citas_registradas").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    tabla.innerHTML = '';
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data().nombre}`);
        
        
        tabla.innerHTML += ` 
        <tr>
        <td>${doc.data().nombre}</td>
        <td>${doc.data().fecha}</td>
        <td>${doc.data().hora}</td>
        <td>${doc.data().telefono}</td>
        <td><button class="btn-danger" onclick="eliminar('${doc.id}')">Eliminar</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn-warning" onclick="editar('${doc.id}','${doc.data().nombre}','${doc.data().fecha}','${doc.data().hora}','${doc.data().telefono}')">Editar</button></td>
        </tr>`
        citas_registradas.orderBy("fecha").limit(2);
    });
});
```

CÓDIGO HTML DE LA TABLA DÓNDE MUESTRA LOS DATOS:

```
<table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                    <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
                    <th scope="col">Hora</th>
                    <th scope="col">Telefono</th>
                    <th scope="col">Eliminar</th>
                    <th scope="col">Editar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tabla">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script con el que logré solucionar el error:

```
db.collection("citas_registradas").orderBy("fecha", "desc")
```